# How to know which logs been deleted in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We can configure Kafka to delete the stored logs after a certain amount of time, my question is:

is there a way to know exactly which logs are deleted? is there a way to know whether or not those deleted logs were consumed by some consumer before deletion?

Answer (score 0):

The LogCleaner logs on the broker have output that specifies which segments are being removed and compacted

For consumption, you can monitor the lag of the consumer group, or start alerting when you get log messages that say the polled offset is not available